# Detect container features in Java EE integration test

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, ejb, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I'm looking for ways / best practices on how to detect the availability of features of the running Java EE container.

Embedded Glassfish for example supports EJBs, Weld EE (as expected) doesn't.
Or how about JPA?

I thought of using JUnit's `assumeThat(XXX)` to decide whether a certain set of integration tests should be executed based on the capabilities of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO what you want to achieve is a bit ridiculous.

You definitely should not deploy your application to containers that don't support some features which your application needs.

If your app is using only Java EE API and a target platform is certified Java EEx server, then you don't have to worry.
Nevertheless, IMO it is a rare case - cause most apps benefit from the capabilities of specific libraries, provided by the server.

Comment: The main purpose here is integration testing, where a CDI-only environment starts like Weld EE starts up faster than a full Java EE server.

Comment: Ok, then you may consider grouping tests into some categories. But still keep in mind that partially skipping tests when running inside some server is an antipattern.